# 2-ish colourability algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

To check if a graph G is 2-colorable is to paint some random vertex green and its adjacent vertices red and so on until you get a valid 2-coloring of the graph or you reach a contradiction where 2 vertices sharing edge have the same colour like R-R or G-G.

This is elegant and fast algorithm for 2-coloring,then I thought what about relaxing the contradiction conditions, so R-R still not allowed but G-G is fine, then for given graph G what is the maximum numbers of R's ?

because any Given graph G can be painted with Green, but we can make it a little better by colouring all but one vertex green and the last one with red.

I tried to give an algorithm for solving it, greedy algorithms was the first things come to mind so find the vertex with least edges and colour it Red and its adjacent Green and repeat, is this algorithm always give the maximum Red's ?

I have to admit that 3-coloring and NP-Complete problem hover above my head fearing that this problem might end up NPC so is it ?

Is there any papers or  math articles that talk about such relaxation from regular colouring ?  if there is I would like a ref to such papers!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only restriction is that two red vertices cannot be adjacent, then the red vertices form an [independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) in the graph, and finding the maximum independent set in a graph (coloring as many vertices red as possible) is indeed one of the classical NP-complete problems.

Here is an easy example to see why the greedy algorithm will not always work well. Take a graph with $130$ vertices: $10$ vertices $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_9$, plus $100$ vertices $b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{99}$, plus $20$ vertices $c_0, c_1, \dots, c_{19}$. Give it the following edges:

- Each vertex $a_i$ is adjacent to vertices $b_i, b_{i+10}, b_{i+20}, \dots, b_{i+90}$.
- Each vertex $c_i$ is adjacent to all $100$ of the vertices $b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{99}$, as well as to each other.

In this graph, the $a$-vertices each have $10$ neighbors, the $b$-vertices each have $21$ neighbors, and the $c$-vertices each have $119$ neighbors.

The greedy algorithm will begin by coloring all of the $a$-vertices red, which means all of the $b$-vertices must be green. (Even after some $a$-vertices have been colored, they will still look good to the greedy algorithm: they have only $10$ uncolored neighbors, and each $b$-vertex has at least $11$.) Then, the greedy algorithm will color one of the $c$-vertices red, and the others green, for a total of $11$ red vertices.

The optimal thing to do is instead to color all the $b$-vertices red. This is over $9$ times better - and by varying up the numbers, we can make the greedy algorithm look arbitrarily bad.